# ¿Cómo obtengo un Token de autenticación haciendo una petición a un WS de tipo Post por URLEncoded C #?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, restsharp

Tengo que hacer un consumo a un servicio web para solicitar un token de autorización, sin embargo este solo recibe parámetros por application/x-www-form-urlencoded.Los datos a enviar son client_id, client_secret y grant_type.
Estoy Utilizando la librería RestSharp y lo que he logrado Codificar es lo siguiente :

```
public void GetTokenn()
    {
        string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URLToken"];
        var client = new RestClient(URL);

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "client_id=123&client_secret=123&grant_type=client_credentials", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    }
```

El resultado de la operación:
Anexo en Imágenes está Headers de la solicitud desde Postman y Body y response desde Postman.

Devuelve un
"StatusCode: 0, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"
[image: Debug]

[image: Headers desde Postman][image: Body y response desde Postman]

Agradezco altamente su ayuda bien sea con la libreria que estoy usando ó con otra. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso parece más bien que estás intentando realizar un GET en lugar de un POST y seguramente la llamada falle porque no haces la petición a la url correcta.

Los POST suelen tener un archivo que es enviado a una url. Los get suelen realizarse a una url que tiene ciertos parámetros adjuntos en ella. Si te fijas en postman pones como url todos los parámetros que insertas en el cuerpo de tu petición post.

Diría que te bastaría con hacer lo siguiente:

```
    public void GetTokenn()
        {
            string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URLToken"];
            var client = new RestClient(URL + "client_id=123&client_secret=123&grant_type=client_credentials");
    
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    
        }
```

Comment: Hola Álvaro, muchas gracias por tu aporte pero no fue la solución, realicé lo que me indicaste y me sigue devolviendo un statuscode 0, incluso repliqué la URL plasmada en PostMan con los parámetros pero no funcionó